# Dynamic loading Angular Controller

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to load controllers dynamically using `ocLazyLoad` :

```
$ocLazyLoad.load('./ctrls/login.js');
```

But am getting this error saying:

> The controller with the name 'loginCtrl' is not registered.

```
angular.module('optimusApp')
    .controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {});
```

**app.js**

```
angular.module("optimusApp", ['ngRoute', 'oc.lazyLoad']);
angular.module('optimusApp')
    .controller('globalCtrl', function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $routeParams, $ocLazyLoad) {
        $ocLazyLoad.load('./ctrls/login.js');
    });
```

Comment: in **app.js** you shouldn't repeat `angular.module('optimusApp')`

Comment: There are two controllers, one separated inside a file and one inside app.js itself

Comment: I know, but that's not the way of declaring controllers. Check my answer and let me know

Answer (score 0):

I made it work by using ng-if

**app.js**

```
var optimusApp = angular.module("optimusApp", ["ngRoute", "oc.lazyLoad"])
    .controller("globalCtrl", function ($rootScope, $location, $http, $routeParams, $ocLazyLoad) {

    $ocLazyLoad.load("./js/app/login.js").then(function() {
         console.log("loginCtrl loaded");
         $rootScope.loginActive = true;
    }, function(e) {
         console.log("error");
    });
});
```

**login.js**

```
optimusApp.controller('loginCtrl', function ($scope, $rootScope, $location, $http) {

});
```

**HTML**

```
<div ng-if="loginActive" ng-controller="loginCtrl">


</div>
```

Basically you will get the "registration error" if your **ng-controller** is in the page before you have the JS loaded.
So the ng-if is a solution, or I see you have ngRoute. So you could set ocLazyLoad to load the controller when entering a specific state.

Comment: Your's doesn't make sense, please recheck the question and let me know

Comment: I makes perfect sense, if you write the code in your files you'll see it will work

Comment: For your satisfaction, I did and it didn't work. I will tell you something, you are invoking a variable which is defined inside another file. How does that work ?

Comment: If the variable is written in plain JS it will be a global variable. Do you know Javascript?

Comment: Ofcourse, but here it is loading but the main problem is the controller is not registering. As I said read the question again.

Comment: which version of angular are you using?

Comment: Am using angular v1.6.1